# An exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:62120/session//element

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core

#### Environment:

- .NET core 3.1
- Nunit 3.12
- Nunit3adapter 3.17
- Selenium Webdriver 3.141
- Chromedriver 84.0.4147.3001 (latest stable version)
- corresponding Chrome Browser 84.0.4147.135
- DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers 3.11

#### Exception:

```
A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL **http://localhost:55162/session//url**. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.: 
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.get_Url()
   at Swat.Extension.WebElementExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<WaitUntilUrlIsChanged>b__0(IWebDriver x)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

#### Issue Description:

For the same test case, it will be quite normal while executing an individual, but while multiple cases executing in order, it will throw the above exception on using `wait.Until()` method after the previous test finished and `driver.Dispose()`.

Can anyone give me some solutions?

#### Highlight remarks:

It seems that the  WebDriver server for URL lost the session id, that is http://localhost:62120/session/SessionId/element, so there are two slashes “//” in the URL.

Comment: Hello. How your problem was solved?

Comment: My workaround is reusing the session id and webdriver uri of last time

Comment: I've been experiencing a similar issue with a similar environment. 
I haven't found a clean solution yet. There is still (as today) an [open issue on Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8030) whihch I think is related and could give you more insights and some workarounds to try out.